# select query related problem

Tags: mysql, select

i have interest rate and amount in a table where interest rate are ranged in different values
like 4.5,4.6,5.2,5.6 etc.

i want to get sum of amounts classified by interest rate where interest rate will be separated
by .25.

for example all amount having interest rate 1.25,1.3,1.4 will be in one group
and 1.5,1.67,1.9 will be in another group

how can i write the query?

Comment: Your question is so confusing

Comment: Why would 1.5 and 1.9 be in the same interest rate group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select min(rate), sum(amount) from interest group by floor(rate / 0.25);
```

Comment: if i want to get interest rate along with amount,then what to do

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT FLOOR(interest*4)/4 AS interest_rate, SUM(amount) AS amount_sum
FROM table_name
GROUP BY interest_rate;
```